# Probability Distribution of a Multivariate Hypergeometric distribution and maximum probability

Tags: random

Hello to all Mathematica Users! I have this question:

Consider a box which contains 69 balls. 17 red, 1 white, 29 blue and 22 green balls. There will be picked 7 balls randomly, without putting the balls back to the experiment.

My question is: How do I create a probability distribution of all the possible combinations and to visualize it? And then I would like to find the combination with the higher probability and the mean.

I know that I have to use "Multivariate Hypergeometric distribution", and I know how to compute the probability of a particular combination, but not how to find the more probable combination and the mean of the whole distribution.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. We appreciate it if you post whatever code you've come up with so far when posting questions -- makes it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 5):

Define the distribution:

```
dist = MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[7, balls = {17, 1, 29, 22}];
```

Just use the relevant functions for summary statistics:

```
Through[{Mean, Variance}[dist]] // N
```

> {{1.72464, 0.101449, 2.94203, 2.23188}, {1.18505, 0.0911573, 1.55504, 
>     1.38613}}

This is challenging to visualize because it is 4-dimensional. One option is to take some random draws and see what pattern they reveal:

```
BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom@8674309;
  sample = RandomVariate[dist, 100]];
BarChart[sample,
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
 ChartStyle -> {Red, White, Blue, Green},
 AspectRatio -> 1/5,
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

There are other ways to visualize this, of course, but we'd need to know more about your needs to make useful suggestions.

You'll need the PDF for probabilities:

```
pdf = PDF[dist, vars = {i, j, k, l}];
```

You can check the probability of any particular combination using rules (this is a piecewise function):

```
pdf /. {i -> 1, j -> 1, k -> 3, l -> 2} // N
```

> 0.0132999

And you can maximize this function to get the most likely combination:

```
MapAt[N, Maximize[pdf, vars, Integers], 1]
```

> {0.106399, {i -> 2, j -> 0, k -> 3, l -> 2}}

Comment: What you have written is quite interesting, but one thing that I don't understand is: Why we have to use the Probability Density Function if we are working with a Multivariate Discrete distribution?